# How to disable scrolling on button click when changing the height of an element?

Tags: scroll, height

So basically I have this "read more" button which changes the height of a div that contains text. When this button is clicked it also scrolls the user back up because the height is changed back.

You can see what I mean by clicking the downwards pointing blue arrow below the text on this page: https://kleijntjetravel.webflow.io/saint-apollinaire.

The used for the content is this

```
<div class="container-p-sub"><p>*Text cut out due to length*</p><div class="lees-meer"></div><a href="#" class="lees-meer-knop></a></div>
```

When clicked on `<a href="#" class="lees-meer-knop"></a>` it changes the height of the paragraph from a fixed position to auto.

I am curious if I'm missing something obvious, or if it is just logically not possible. Thanks for responding in advance and I appreciate the time you took to read this post! :)